# Creating custom route in ASP NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a MainController with an Index action. I want to pass in Index action the last fragment of request url. I have tried this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Main",
            "Main/#!/{alias}",
            new { controller = "Main", action = "Index" }
        );
```

with this Index action:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string alias)
    {
        // code
    }
```

but this is not working. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This way

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Main",
            "Main/#!/{alias}",
            new { controller = "Main", action = "Index", alias= UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```